# Apache Kylin installation without Sandbox

Tags: hadoop, kylin

I was wondering if there are any resources regarding Apache Kylin installation without any sandbox (like cloudera, hortonworks) support. I have managed to do the following:

1. Install Hadoop 2.6
2. Install Hive
3. Install HBase

Then I used the binary from kylin site and so far been able to run it. The problem start when I try to build a cube, the map reduce job gets stuck in step 2. I am thinking if it is still assuming to be in sandbox mode and not submitting job to hadoop at all (there is no entry in hadoop jobtracker).

So I need solution regarding the two:
1. Possible configuration of kylin in pure hadoop setup (no sandbox)
2. somehow enable the kylin setup to submit job to hadoop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such sandbox or non-sandbox configuration in Kylin. Just make sure the machine where Kylin runs has hadoop setup correctly and you should be fine.

Under the scene, `kylin.sh` uses `hbase classpath` and `hive -e set | grep 'env:CLASSPATH'` to detect hadoop settings. Double check these commands work as expect if you are not sure what cluster Kylin connects to.

If Kylin has problem submitting MR jobs, check two places. First is hadoop resource manager, see if the job has really been submitted or not. Sometimes it's just running slow. Second check `kylin.log`, see if any exception there. Post the log to kylin dev mailing list and someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can install hadoop-2.6 , hive-0.14 ,hbase-0.98.8-hadoop2 with Zookeeper inbuilt or external zookeeper-3.5
Now you can run kylin-v1.1-release on it
If you still face Issues paste the log here